# JavaScript How to loop between 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, loops

Im trying to make a loop where i have `let sum = 0`
When i click on a button Sum goes to 1 and when i press the button again it goes back to 0, and loop it every time i press the button

```
let sum = 0


button.addEventListener("click", loop())


function loop(){

}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to loop over? Or are you just saying toggle between 1 and 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call it toggle not loop, it will be like this

```
function toggle(){
 sum = sum==0 ? 1:0;
}
```

so every time it will switch between these 2 numbers

Comment: Ah man i still have tons to learn, ive been trying Switch cases, for loops, forEach like 10 line codes yet all it was needed was this and it even makes sense lol...tyvm!!!!!

Comment: please appreciate with +1

Comment: @CrveniFlash in your event handler, make sure your don't add the () to the function call too.

Comment: @imvain2 yeah figured that one also :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off you should remove the `(` `)` from the listener callback.

Try this:

```js
let sum = 0

button.addEventListener("click", loop)

function loop(){
  sum = sum ? 0 : 1
}
```